# regex pandas with multiple potential patterns

Tags: regex, pandas

I have:

```
blah blah blah (3383-HK) - blah blah blah
blah blah blah (A-US) - blah blah blah
blah blah blah (blah) (3383-HK) - blah blah blah
blah blah blah (A.CC-US) - blah blah blah
```

I want to extract the stock ticker from each line.

```
(3383-HK
(A-US
(3383-HK
(A.CC-US
```

the stock ticker format is:

- enclosed in brackets
- has the format XXX-XXX, or XXX.XXX-XXX where XXX are alphanumeric characters ranging in length from 1 to 20 characters in each section

Currently, I use:

```
df['ticker_region']=df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\(\w{1,20}-\w{1,20})")
```

and it returns:

```
(3383-HK
(3383-HK
(A.CC-US
```

but NOT:
(A.CC-US

Is there a recommended way to extract the last one as well?

I tried:

```
df['ticker_region']=df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\(\w{1,20}\.?\w{1,10}?-\w{1,20})")
```

but it is not working, as it does not grab:

```
(A-US
```

my full script is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'filename':[    "blah blah blah (3383-HK) - blah blah blah",
    "blah blah blah (A-US) - blah blah blah",
    "blah blah blah (blah) (3383-HK) - blah blah blah",
    "blah blah blah (A.CC-US) - blah blah blah"]})
df['ticker_region']=df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\(\w{1,20}\.?\w{1,10}?-\w{1,20})") # search for (XXXXXXX-XXXXX
df['ticker_region2']=df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\(\w{1,20}.{1,20}?-\w{1,20})") # search for (XXXXXXX-XXXXX
df['ticker_region3']=df['filename'].str.extract(r"(\(\w{1,20}-\w{1,20})") # search for (XXXXXXX-XXXXX

df
```

Comment: There are too many descriptions, but you do not explain the requirements. Do you mean the codes must adhere to some rules, like 1) start with `(`, 2) then there must be 1 to 20 word chars with a single optional dot in between, 3) then `-`, 4) then any 1 to 20 letters, digits, `_`s? Or do you really just extract text between parentheses?

Comment: question has been updated showing the extraction requirements

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429859/3832970) assuming that the `.` in the first "word" is counted towards the length limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\(((?=[\w.]{1,20}-)\w+(?:\.\w+)?-\w{1,20})\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4AuUB/6)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `((?=[\w.]{1,20}-)\w+(?:\.\w+)?-\w{1,20})` - Group 1 (returned by `Series.str.extract`):

  - `(?=[\w.]{1,20}-)` - there must be 1 to 20 word or `.` chars and then `-` immediately to the right of the current location
  - `\w+`  - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\.\w+)?`  an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ word chars
  - `-` - a `-` char
  - `\w{1,20}` - 1 to 20 word chars
- `\)` - a `)` char

Answer (score 0):

```
df.A.str.extract(r'\(([\w\.?]+-.*)\)')
```

**Output**

```
          0
0   3383-HK
1   A-US
2   3383-HK
3   A.CC-US
```